# Choosing a safe number of members for a CP Subsystem

Tags: cluster-computing, hazelcast, consensus, raft

Tried scouring the documentation, but I'm still uncertain about the CP Subsystem setup for my current situation.

We have a Hazelcast cluster spread across 2 data centers, each data center having an even number of members, say 4, but can have as many as double during rollout.

The boxes in each data center are configured to be part of a separate partition group => 2 data centers - 2 partition groups, with 4-8 members each at a snapshot in time.

What would be the best number to set as CP Subsystem member count, considering that one data center might be decoupled as part of BAU?

I initially thought of setting the count to 5, to enforce having at least one box from each data center in the Raft consensus as a general situation (rollover happens only for a short amount of time during redeployment, so maybe it is not that big of a deal), but that might mean that consensus will not be possible when one data center will be decoupled. On the other hand, if I set up a value smaller than the box count in one dc, say 3, what would happen if all the boxes in the consensus group were to be assigned in the same dc and that dc would go away abruptly due to network conditions? These are mostly assumptions, since CP is a relatively new topic for me, so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you use *three* data-centers? It's much, much easier with three.

Comment: @michael-deardeuff, unfortunately, no. Only 2 dcs available. Also, as I understand it, the current setup is to ensure that each primary partition has its secondary counterpart in the other dc, so that no data loss will happen in case a full dc goes down at any time, so creating an artificial partition group out of boxes from the 2 existing ones might actually lead to losing data, since we could have primary and secondary assigned to boxes in the same dc.

Comment: Spreading a cluster across data centers is not a good design, and for various good reasons. I understand the possible reasons - dynamic scale-out/scale-in but its not a good strategy nonetheless when it is done over multiple DCs. Any possibility you can try WAN Replication? That ways one DC will be a cluster on its own and the other cluster can be shutdown when not needed. And it then becomes trivial to configure CP subsystem for the individual cluster.

Answer (score 0):

We prefer three datacenters, but sometimes a third is not available.

My team was faced with this same decision several years ago when expanding into a new jurisdiction. There were a lot of options, here are some. In all of these scenarios we did **extensive testing for how the system behaved with network partitions**.

#### Make a primary datacenter and a secondary datacenter

This is the option we ended up going with. We put 2/3 of the hosts in one datacenter and 1/3 in the secondary data-center. As much as possible, we weighted client traffic towards the primary datacenter. We also communicated with our customers about this preference so they could do the same if they wanted.

If the datacenter had multiple rooms, we made sure to have hosts spread across the different rooms to help mitigate power/network outages within the datacenter. At the minimum, we ensured the hosts are on different racks.

We also had multiple clusters and for each cluster we usually switched which datacenter was the primary and which was the secondary. We didn't do this in some jurisdictions with notorious power troubles.

#### Split half and half

It's up to the gods what happens when a datacenter goes down. This is why we chose the first option: we wanted the choice of what happens when each datacenter goes down.

#### Have a tie-breaker in a different region

Put a host in an entirely different region from the two datacenters. Most of the time the latency will be too high for this host to fully participate in making consensus decisions, but in the case of a network partition it can help move the majority to one of the partitions.

The tie-breaker host *must* be a part of the quorum and cannot be kicked out because of latency delays.

#### Build a new datacenter

These things are very expensive, but it makes the durability story much nicer. Not always an option.